# YUI and bootstrap should they be used together

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yui

I was thinking of making my UI using bootstrap but all my client side scripting is done in YUI can anyone tell me will it create problem for me if I use bootstrap since it's based on jquery.

On first I thought it will not create problems but on longer run I feel it can since all my client side validations and error message will be done using YUI not by jquery.

And one more thing i came upon this site when I was searching for the solution http://jshirley.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#

But many of the components are under construction and some of them were not working so is this library reliable or should I use purecss which was my last option.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Bootstrap CSS without using the Bootstrap JS plugins.

That's probably the best way to go, and then you won't be limited by whichever JavaScript library you decide to use.

Alternatively, you can use YUI and jQuery together on the same page, if there is a Bootstrap JS plugin that you really want to use.  There won't be any conflicts if that's what you want to do, though I'm not sure I'd recommend that.

Pure CSS is also a good option to consider, but in general, if you're building a custom site, don't limit yourself by what plugins are available to just drop in.

EDIT: Check out [AlloyUI](http://alloyui.com/) by Liferay! It's a library that extends YUI, and they use Bootstrap's CSS extensively with their widgets.

Answer (score 0):

if you're interested in using Ratchet toggle with YUI: https://github.com/mschipperheyn/yui3-gallery/tree/master/src/gallery-msa-checkbox. We switched completely to Bootstrap while having been on YUI for a while and never looked back.